# Generating cross-platform eBooks on a Mac?

Tags: books

I would like to produce an electronic textbook for distribution to my students. Ideally, this would have some of the interactive features like those available in [iBooks Author](http://www.apple.com/ibooks-author/), but I think the book will need to be compatible on Windows and Linux as well; I don't necessarily want a Kindle or Nook-compatible book, as I'm positive that won't support the interactive features and animations I'd like to include.

Are there any solutions that will allow me to create and publish such a book? It's not necessary to distribute it via an eBook store, and I would prefer a solution that didn't involve continual subscription fees (such as [Adobe Creative Cloud/Digital Publishing Suite](http://www.adobe.com/products/digital-publishing-suite-family/buying-guide-pricing.edu.html)). Or do I just need to make different versions for the different platforms, with varying levels of features on each? (Less desirable, but possible.)

Comment: For cross platform .epub format is the only solution I think.  Pages can export to that.  Whether it has the features you want you will just have to see.

Comment: I've revised the question to make it clearer—I want compatibility with Windows and Linux. I don't need Kindle or Nook support. Nor will ePUB work, as its feature set is too limited.

Comment: What features does ePub fail to have? and what format do you currently use?

Comment: Unless the EPUB format changed in the last few months, there's no support for animations. I'd like to show "movies" explaining physical processes, but my understanding was EPUB doesn't require this to be supported by readers. Currently, I don't have an ebook—I want to know what my options are before committing to iBooks or another format.

Comment: For your compatibility requirements epub is really the only choice.  I suggest you explore more closely what epub3 can do and adapt your book to it.  Otherwise you have to go the different formats for differant platforms route.

Comment: Assuming I can use ePUB3, then, what are the workflow options for producing it, since iBooks won't be Linux- or  Windows-compatible?

Comment: As TomG said earlier, you can export to EPUB from Pages, or use one of numerous utilities which may do a questionable job (as far as that goes, Pages may, too, but EPUB is really the only cross-platform ebook format).